# Using a single cell serving as an ID source for formulas to import data from

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have my master Google sheet and I need a weekly updated Excel report to be imported into that sheet. Right now I use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; IMPORTRANGE("XYZ"; "'Overview'!A4:FZ"); 10; 0);))
```

Here is the tricky part - I transform the Excel sheet into a Google sheet and it always receives a new link/sheet ID so to get the data from the newest version I need to change all links in all formulas in my master sheet.

My idea is if it's possible to make one cell that would serve as an ID source that I can weekly change to the newest sheet ID and it would be automatically imported from that specific sheet for all formulas.

The report sheet is extremely extensive so I want to avoid copying all data into my master sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by referencing ID in a cell like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; IMPORTRANGE(A1; "Overview!A4:FZ"); 10; 0); ))
```

where A1 will be: **`16nnuzNRx_kGGJm1EBV57kBT2bfW1-2TYwSiuaLF-QIA`** or the whole URL.